# Example logging to Splunk w/ React 16+

Tags: reactjs, splunk, splunk-sdk

**I am looking for examples showing how to write log messages to Splunk from a React JS 16+ application.**  Splunk has a TypeScript snippet in their docs, but I am interested in seeing how others have tied it into the React framework so everything is configured and initialized properly for use in the application.

Note: I've considered using log4js with a custom appender for Splunk but haven't found any examples for that either!